# Unable to export full log information from Applications insights

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm using azure functions which is integrated with application insights. While exporting the data from application insights , I'm able to see only 1898 records. How do I get complete logging information data exported to excel without creating azure  data explorer cluster (I don't have permissions to create it)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by running a `kql` query in the logs of Application Insights from `Function App`

From the Azure Portal,
Go to  `Function App -> ApplicationInsights -> Logs`  and

Execute the below **Kql query**:

```sql
union
    availabilityResults,
    requests,
    exceptions,
    pageViews,
    traces,
    customEvents,
    dependencies
| where timestamp > datetime("2022-10-14T12:02:57.123Z") and timestamp < datetime("2022-10-15T12:02:57.123Z")
| order by timestamp desc
```

***Log information from Application Insights***:

[image]

[*Refer: How to use Union Operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer)